# Chrome and Chromium: share profile and cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I'm considering migrating from Chrome to Chromium due to the licencing and graphics acceleration support.

To avoid setup and save disk space, I am thinking of symlinking:

- `~/.config/google-chrome` to `~/.config/chromium`
- `~/.cache/google-chrome` to `~/.cache/chromium`

Assuming I only want to run one instance of a web browser at a time, I'm guessing that the locking of `~/.config/{browser}/SingletonLock` should work fine.

I've searched around and not seen this approach before. I believe that both browsers share a huge percentage of code base, so I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Apart from "backup, try it and see", would there be any gotchas to look out for or reasons not to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried sharing the profiles via symlink and got this message:

[image: error]

Versioning is one blocker for sharing one profile between the two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from versioning issues (as mentioned by Tom’s post), Chrome and Chromium also use different secrets.

You can mitigate that by making sure both are setup for the same. E.g. assuming you’re using `--password-store=gnome-libsecret`:

```bsh
# set chromium to use the same secret as chrome
# Warning: this makes all previously saved passwords in chromium unreadable!
secret-tool lookup application chrome | secret-tool store
    --label="Chrome Safe Storage" application chromium
```